# Keeping ExpressJS Application Running After Terminal is Closed

Tags: node.js, express, terminal

My application, working on server, but then I close the terminal window and your application stops. How can I solve this issue.

- How to make a application run permanently in background ?
- Is there any Express plugins for solving this issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could found answer from ExpressJs official guide about **[Process managers for Express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html#forever)**.

**[PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)** and **[Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)** is recommended by official document for keeping your application running background and automatically restarts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shell screen:[screen commands](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy)

1. Install screen : `sudo apt install screen`
2. Create a screen : `Ctrl-a c`
3. Go to your app folder and run app: `node server.js` (check any nodes api tp confirm your app is working)
4. Detach screen : `Ctrl-a d`
5. List screens to check your app is running: `screen -ls`
6. Close terminal.

PS: To attach the screen your app is running

1. List available screens : `screen -ls`
2. Attach screen : `screen -r {pid}`

Kill a screen using : `screen -X -S {pid} quit`